# Edit pixel values in an image as numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-3.6

I am reading an image like so:

```
img = np.array(Image.open(test_dir + image_name))
```

What I want to do is find a region in the array where the value is high (250 or more) and reduce it by 10:

```
rows = img.shape[0]
cols = img.shape[1]
pixel = []
for x in range(0,rows):
    for y in range(0, cols):
        if x >= 122 and x <= 160 and y >= 34  and y <= 71:
            if img[x,y]>= 250:
                img[x,y] = img[x,y] -10
                pixel.append(img[x,y])
```

So the region I am looking at according the the unaltered image should be a box from (122, 34) to (160,71), and it should have some pixels over 250, but somehow when I run this code I end up with nothing in the pixel list

Answer (score 1):

Is `img` a 3 dimensional array? If so, then your test `img[x, y] >= 250` is testing if an array of 3 elements is greater than 250. This will result in an error and cause your script to terminate at that point. You did not say if this is happening.

If it is a 3 dimensional array and you want to check if **all** channels have value greater than 250 at position x, y, then you have to check for `np.all(img[x, y] >= 250)` instead of `img[x, y] >= 250`.

In general you want to avoid loops and use vectorized operations to speed things up.

```
min_row = 122
max_row = 161
min_col = 34
max_col = 72
threshold = 250

row_slice = slice(min_row, max_row)
col_slice = slice(min_col, max_col)
roi = img[row_slice, col_slice] >= threshold
img[row_slice, col_slice][roi] -= 10
```

or more succinctly but less readable,

```
roi = img[min_row:max_row, min_col:max_col] >= threshold
img[min_row:max_row, min_col:max_col][roi] -= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is one line:

```
im[im>250]-=10
```

**Demonstration**

Start with this 8x8 gradient image:

[image]

Here it is enlarged:

[image]

Then use **IPython** like this:

```
# Load image as L (greyscale)
im = np.array(Image.open('image.png').convert('L'))

# View contents
im
Out[16]: 
array([[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219],
       [182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182],
       [146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146],
       [109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109],
       [ 73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73],
       [ 36,  36,  36,  36,  36,  36,  36,  36],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)

# Do required processing
im[im>250]-=10

# Review contents
In [18]: im
Out[18]: 
array([[245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245, 245],
       [219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219],
       [182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182],
       [146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146, 146],
       [109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109],
       [ 73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73],
       [ 36,  36,  36,  36,  36,  36,  36,  36],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Let's try decreasing even more pixels, just for fun:

```
In [19]: im[im>100]-=10

In [20]: im
Out[20]: 
array([[235, 235, 235, 235, 235, 235, 235, 235],
       [209, 209, 209, 209, 209, 209, 209, 209],
       [172, 172, 172, 172, 172, 172, 172, 172],
       [136, 136, 136, 136, 136, 136, 136, 136],
       [ 99,  99,  99,  99,  99,  99,  99,  99],
       [ 73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73,  73],
       [ 36,  36,  36,  36,  36,  36,  36,  36],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more compact solution you can try

```
roi = img[122:161, 34:72]
pixel = roi[roi >= 250]
roi[roi >= 250] -= 10
```

Comment: Neither roi or pixel are used in the final line... Please review.

Comment: @Benjamin Actually, I just looked at this more carefully and, you are correct, the first 2 lines are not needed, but... the final line works on its own as it is the same as my answer which I demonstrated to work in my answer.

Comment: @Benjamin You are right about `roi`, I've fixed that, thanks. As for, the second line, it isn't explicitly asked but the code in the original question also extracts the values of the pixels in the variable `pixel`

Comment: @MarkSetchell The first line is actually needed since the OP just wants to search within a certain area.

Comment: There has been an edit here that makes my comment ambiguous... and pixel is still not being used.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your image is grayscale this will do it.

```
inds = np.where(img>=250)
inds = inds[(inds.T[0]>=122)&(inds.T[0]<=160)&(inds.T[1]>=34)&(inds.T[1]<=71)]
img[inds]-=10
```